# Is there a way to export PhpStorm code style rules as .eslintrc?

Tags: visual-studio-code, phpstorm, eslint

I've been using PhpStorm for awhile, for PHP as well as JS. I would love, however, to switch to VSCode since it's lighter, open source and free. But one feature that I cannot quite carry over with extensions is Code Style settings.

PhpStorm has a sweet visual interface in settings that allows you to set up detailed code style rules with live examples right there. ESLint, unfortunately, doesn't have anything similar - it's all text rules (which is a drag and takes forever to set up).

So I'm wondering if there's any way at all to export PhpStorm code style settings as ESLint rules? Or if there's an app that has a similar interface to set up ESLint? Or maybe there's a VScode extension that I am missing that has a similar interface?

Comment: no; PhpStorm can import code style settings from `.eslintrc`, but no vice versa

Comment: @lena that's too bad... Do you know of any other way to migrate those settings to eslint? Apart from manual, that is.

Comment: I did find a helpful tool to generate .eslintrc, but it's not as powerful as it should be: https://eslint.org/demo